# TypeError while installing npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm not very familiar with js-related technologies and now having trouble with package installation.
Log file contains these lines:

```
1469 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property '2.2.2' of undefined
1469 verbose stack     at setData (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:135:27)
1469 verbose stack     at RES (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:23:14)
1469 verbose stack     at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
1469 verbose stack     at fixName (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\add-named.js:29:5)
1469 verbose stack     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache\caching-client.js:173:7)
1469 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:210:7
1469 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

and unfortunately it tells me absolutely nothing. Haven't even a slight idea where to dig in for resolution. Maybe someone could guide?

Comment: The property suggests that you don't have a package installed.  Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact command I initiated.

Comment: After some exploration I found out that an inability to resolve particular package in the dependencies causes this error. If I specify the version of it as latest (*) I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined".

Comment: What does your package.json look like? Specifically the dependencies part

Answer (score 0):

Check `package.json` file in the root of your `project` and mark the dependency with version number `2.2.2` as `*`

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "underscore": "*",
  }
```

like this. 
then run `npm install` again.

Comment: In that case I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined".